# InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type, but this ViewDataDictionary instance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[image]

above is what i'm trying to achieve in my the view

i'm not sure what could be wrong or missing in my controller and view. when the page loads i get this error. if i return the view to a list, how do i convert model ListAccumation ToList()? if this what i need to do

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'ExposureTracker.Models.Accumulation', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ExposureTracker.Models.Accumulation]

```js
<--Controller-->
public IActionResult ViewDetails(string Identifier)
{
  var ListAccumulation = new Accumulation();
  var Account= _db.dbLifeData.Where(y => y.identifier == Identifier);
  var userDetails = Account.FirstOrDefault(x => x.identifier == Identifier);
  string strFullname = userDetails.fullName;
  string strDOB = userDetails.dateofbirth;
  foreach(var item in Account)
   {
     if(item.baserider == "BASIC")
      {
       ListAccumulation.insuredprod = item.benefittype;
       ListAccumulation.basictotalsumassured += item.sumassured;
       ListAccumulation.basictotalreinsuredamount += item.reinsurednetamountatrisk;         
      }
    }
      return View("ViewAccumulation", ListAccumulation);
}

 public IActionResult ViewAccumulation()
 {
   return View();
 }
```

```html
@model IEnumerable<Accumulation>
<div class="table-responsive-md mb-1 mt-5">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="basic-datatables" cellspacing="0">
            <thead class="bg-dark text-light">
                <tr>
                    <th>Insured Prod</th>
                    <th>Sum Assured/Face Amount</th>
                    <th>Reinsured Net Amount At Risk</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach(var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.insuredprod</td>
                        <td>@item.basictotalsumassured   </td>
                        <td>@item.basictotalreinsuredamount</td>

                    </tr>
                  }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Change your code:

```
var ListAccumulation = new Accumulation();
```

into

```
 var ListAccumulation = new List<Accumulation>();
```

2.Change your foreach like below:

```
var accumulations = Account.Where(x => x.baserider == "BASIC").Select(x => new Accumulation
                {
                    insuredprod = x.benefittype,
                    basictotalsumassured = x.sumassured,
                    basictotalreinsuredamount = x.reinsurednetamountatrisk
                });
ListAccumulation.AddRange(accumulations);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this one. it actually helps out though what i'm trying to achieve here is to add each item from Account in to the ListAccumulation whereas my view will return the items through the ListAccumulation.. i have an else condition next to the 'IF' each item in Account  if condition is true will add the item to the ListAccumulation 'ELSE IF' will add a new row of item to the ListAccumulation... sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Veck Please see my update answer.

Comment: Hi @Qing Guo, how do i accumulate the amounts in the  var accumulation? for example 

there are multiple rows in the var accumulation,  i need to add all amounts  for BASIC for sum assured and reinsured net amounts? and return the result to the view.  using the  linq query above it will not add the total amounts for basic and its the total amounts i need to display in view. if its BASIC. no need to add a new row. just add all the amounts and display in a single row

Comment: Hi @Qing Guo, i've updated my question above. see the example of what i'm trying to achieve. Thank you for kind assistance

Comment: @Veck This is an another new question. You could ask a new question and tell us what you want clearly  . Update in this question may make  the confusion.

Comment: I see. i'l just post a new question. thank you Qing Guo.